# do files with .nii extensions have delimeters?

Tags: file, delimiter

Just like .csv files are seperated by comma delimeter. Am unable to determine the delimeters for .nii files. I would like to arrange the datasets in .nii files.

Comment: The `.nii` file extension does not appear on [the Wikipedia page for file extentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions_(M–R)#N). A quick look [filext.com](https://filext.com/file-extension/NII) shows it's a propriety file type used by Neuroimaging Informatics Technology Initiative - is this the type of file you're talking about?

Comment: Yes Neuroimaging Informatics file